# What are the verbs that are not used in the progressive?

Tags: verbs, progressive-aspect

There are verbs that generally don't take the progressive suffix "-ing", like *hate* and not *hating:* "I hate that," not "I am hating that."

This also applies to other verbs like *want, need, like,* etc. Standard English does not have "I am wanting a sandwich" when describing a simple indication of need.

Could you please tell me if there are other verbs that don't take "ing"? Perhaps there's a special term. If there are exceptions, mention those for me.

Comment: What's wrong with the words *hating, wanting, needing, liking*, etc?

Comment: @Lawrence They are not generally used in sentences such as "I am really hating that; I am wanting a sandwich; I am needing a hug..." which is what I believe the question is about.

Comment: I can't offhand think of a verb that cannot accept "-ing".  Certainly there are some where the use is less idiomatic such that it sounds "illiterate", but these are still legitimate from a grammar standpoint.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thanks. But that doesn't make the *-ing* words themselves invalid, given a slightly different sentence. For example, "*He'll be wanting to make some changes*" is a common construction in AuE. Here's a BrE example: [*He'll be wanting to talk to her*](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=B0gjIpWrgCoC&pg=PT26&lpg=PT26&dq=%22he%27ll+be+wanting+to%22&source=bl&ots=2_opw6R4V5&sig=CC7RlPX16Id40ruwXr604SnOPaY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjsyf7Qut_aAhXCKZQKHdNfDhgQ6AEITTAK#v=onepage&q=%22he'll%20be%20wanting%20to%22&f=false). It's not the *-ing* verbs themselves that are problematic, it seems.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Interestingly, if we change *am* to *find myself* in your examples above, the phrases might pass without comment.

Comment: Yes, but then you have changed the main verb.

Comment: The question is fine per se with Andrew's edit, but I won't vote to re-open as the term 'stative verb', the blocking of continuous constructions, and the exceptions have all been given in previous answers.

Comment: @Lawrence see https://english.stackexchange.com/a/103643/44619 and https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150616/is-it-really-wrong-to-say-im-hearing/150658#150658 The question even before Andrew's edit was quite clear, but unless you have never taught ESL before, you wouldn't be aware that this "problem" existed.

Comment: @HotLicks look at this older question, and then you'll see why Andrew's answer now makes sense [Stative verbs in the continuous form?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/187261/stative-verbs-in-the-continuous-form)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I've voted to reopen because I could not find an older question that specifically asks for the term "stative" and/or a list of the verbs that are not usually used in the present continuous tense. If you have better luck finding it then we could close the OP as being a duplicate.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A list? 'We're seeing a lot of computer viruses these days.' / 'Social scientists are now understanding the great impact of technology on everyday life.' / 'You're just now realizing that I have needs, too?' and 'We're [really] loving our new home' are examples of [often?] stative (or in the case of 'realise',  ing-resistant inchoative?) verbs used in continuous constructions from [the Grammar Exchange](http://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/340600179/m/6306002132).  But they're not used this way all that often. A list would be dubious as well as off-topic here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth see, love, understand... yeah, I get it. But nobody is saying these verbs have only one meaning and to only use the simple present form. The question is on topic, it's about English, it[s about usage, it's about effective communication and I think visitors will find this page helpful.  No one is going to get hurt or offended if a summary list of verbs is posted e.g. verbs of the senses, e.g. see, here, ... verbs of preference e.g. like, adore, ... etc. It's not a list of references or random words/expressions.

Comment: @Mari-Lou They've largely one meaning (though 'understand' may be inchoative or stative). Essentially, this is a request for 'verbs not usable in progressive constructions round about 80-90% of the time'. It's imprecise to the point of being unhelpful. Individual verbs in this area need individual treatments.

Comment: ... [Mignon Fogarty's article 'Is "I'm Loving It" Proper Grammar?'](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/is-im-loving-it-proper-grammar) gives a reasonably balanced overview with a list of sorts.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. There have been other questions addressing particular verbs resisting continuous  constructions. Asking for a list is neither on-topic here nor helpful (it's usually not a yes/no property).

Answer (score 1):

The term is *stative verb:* these are verbs talking about states or situations, and are connected with thinking and opinions, feeling and emotions, things are not actually actions.

The British Council has a good explanation on their [Learn English website](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/stative-verbs):

> Some verbs are not usually used in the continuous form, even when we are talking about temporary situations or states. These are called **stative verbs.**
>
> 1. Stative verbs are often verbs connected with thinking and opinions.
>
>    She doesn’t know what to do
>      *She isn’t knowing what to do
> 2. Other stative verbs are connected with feelings and emotions
>
>    I like this song. Who sings it?
>      *I’m liking this song

[Aside: note that *Who sings it?* is probably wrong here, and *Who is singing it?* would be more usual, because *sing* is an action.]

> 3. ‘see’, ‘hear’, ‘taste’, ‘smell’, ‘feel’ are verbs that describe senses.
>
>    These verbs aren’t usually used in continuous forms. They are often used with ‘can’.
>
>    It smells of smoke in here.
>      *It’s smelling of smoke in here.
> 4. Stative verbs describe things that are not actions.
>
>    He smells of fish.
>      He’s smelling the fish.
>
> The second sentence is an action – not a state. The man wants to know if the fish is OK to eat.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, that's why I used "probably". I think the progressive aspect is far more likely, and the simple present tense is restricted to the usage you mention.

Comment: I am not in disagreement with anything you say, but I'm not sure it answers the question - since I don't understand the question.

Comment: @WS2 If you don't understand the question, please comment on the question.

Comment: "Stative verb" is the term for *what*?  What does it have to do with "-ing"?

Comment: @HotLicks I refer you to the asterisked sentences in my answer.

Comment: And what to the asterisks mean?  Your "answer" is nearly as unclear as the question.

Comment: @HotLicks See the [Help pages](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and scroll down to "What notation and symbols are currently used here?" This is a site for serious enthusiasts and those symbols have been in use in the subject generally for so long and used so often here that I'd expect them to be known.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - But how are your starred examples wrong?  They're simply less idiomatic usages.

Comment: @Hot Right, a question mark would be [more appropriate.](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/340/2555)

Comment: If you don't like an answer, write your own! Also: bear in mind that this is a quote. The quoted passage indicated that the construction is wrong.

Comment: How the f*** does this answer get 3 downvotes? Is it because Andrew didn't pepper every line with "probably", "usually", "normally" and  "with exceptions" etc?

Comment: @Mari-LouA - It's because he didn't answer the question, but simply raised more questions.  No one has so far identified a verb which cannot take "-ing".  And the "rule" that stative verbs cannot be used in present continuous is really just a guideline for those learning the language, as some present continuous constructions with static verbs are not idiomatic, even though they are perfectly legitimate from a grammar standpoint, and might very well be used (in the right situation) by literate English speakers.

Comment: @HotLicks but precisely the British Council excerpt is a "guideline" for speakers of English as a 2nd language. There's nothing dogmatic in their explanation: *“These verbs* ***aren’t usually used in continuous forms***. *They are often used with ‘can’.”*

Comment: @Mari-LouA - But there's no **rule** here.  You can construct present continuous statements using stative verbs and not violate any grammar rules.  The only thing is that you run a higher than average risk of producing something that doesn't "sound right".  But English is loaded with such potential scenarios.

Comment: @HotLicks where does Andrew's answer mention rules or the fact that using those verbs in the  present progressive is "wrong"? He doesn't but it's nevertheless true that we don't normally say "My kids are believing in Father Christmas" The statement  may be grammatical but it's not idiomatic (although "believe", another [stative verb](https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/stative-verbs.html), was left out in this answer).

Comment: I'm going to end up deleting these comments (or at least get another mod to review them). **If you have a better answer, *write your own.***